# How to build a URL with commas to query with filters using flask-wtforms jinja QuerySelectField and python operators "eq,gt,lt,et"

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

This is a flask front end to an Accounting database.

I am struggling to create a form to pass a query back to veiw function, I need to query one or more columns out of eleven columns at once, I have the code for the backend side after somebody helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392535/flask-multiple-parameters-how-to-avoiding-multiple-if-statements-when-querying-m) but I dont know how to build a URL like this:

```
books?filter=aux,eq,FILCUI&credit,eq,445663
```

where eq are operators from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). These I can use as a dropdown list to have "eqaul too" "greater than" "not eqaul". Brilliant

Six of my eleven columns have relationships with other tables, when I add a new row with a form I use QuerySelectField to have the correct entries, I often need to add or update the five parent tables so using QuerySelectField is a must. My code for the form is this:

```
    <div class="AUX">
        <form action="{{ url_for('books.books', filter=selectaux) }}" method="GET">
            {{ aux_form.selectaux(class="input") }}{{ aux_form.submitaux(class="submit") }}
        </form>
    </div>
```

which out puts this:`http://192.168.0.45/books?selectaux=ATTMAR&submitaux=submit`

I have looked at these :- [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/) [creating urls](https://overiq.com/flask-101/creating-urls-in-flask/) [multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768370/jinja-flask-and-wtforms-how-to-pass-parameters-in-field) and [dynamic urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738331/using-flask-wtforms-how-do-i-style-my-form-section-of-the-html) But the answers arent obvious enough for me, sorry!
Also I am using "GET"  as the method, is this write? here is my veiw function.

```
@bp.route("/books", methods=["GET"])
def books():
    args = flask.request.args
    filters = create_filters(args.get("filter"))
    query = Book.query.order_by(Book.date.desc())
    query = filter_query(filters, query, Book)
    aux_form = SearchAuxForm()
    add_form = AddBookForm()
    books = []
    def get_books(offset=0,per_page=100):
        return books[offset: offset + per_page]
    for book in query.all():
        books.append(dict(
            id=book.id,
            date=book.date,
            description=book.description,
            debit=book.debit,
            credit=book.credit,
            montant=book.montant,
            AUX=book.AUX,
            TP=book.TP,
            REF=book.REF,
            JN=book.JN,
            PID=book.PID,
            CT=book.CT
        ))
    page, per_page, offset = get_page_args(page_parameter='page',
                                       per_page_parameter='per_page')
    total = len(books)
    pagination_books = get_books(offset=offset,per_page=per_page)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, total=total)
    return render_template('books/books.html', title='Books', page=page, books=pagination_books,
                       per_page=per_page, pagination=pagination, aux_form=aux_form, add_form=add_form)
```

all help or ideas much neede to help this simpleton!

EDIT:
Here is my code for AuxSearchForm followed by How I imagine the form might look like:

```
class SearchAuxForm(FlaskForm):
    selectaux = QuerySelectField('Aux', query_factory=AUX, get_label='id')
    submitaux = SubmitField('submit')

class SearchForm(FlaskForm)
    date = DateField('date', validators=[DataRequired()])
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    description = StringField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    debit = QuerySelectField('Debit', query_factory=debit, get_label='id')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    credit = QuerySelectField('Credit', query_factory=credit, get_label='id')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    montant = FloatField('Montant', validators=[DataRequired()])
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    AUX = QuerySelectField('Auxilliare', query_factory=AUX, get_label='id')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    TP = QuerySelectField('Type', query_factory=TP, get_label='id')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    REF = StringField('REF')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    JN = QuerySelectField('JN', query_factory=JN, get_label='id')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    PID = QuerySelectField('PID', query_factory=PID, get_label='id')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    CT = IntegerField('CT')
    operator = SelectField('op', choices=['eq', 'eq'), ('ne','ne'), ('lt', 'lt'), ('gt', 'gt'), ('le', 'le'), ('ge','ge')
    submit = SubmitField('submit')
```

This second form (I only intend to have one form) will enable me to query each row for a value "operator", and also query two or more rows in the same manner, I hope that is understandable!
Warm regards Paul

Comment: Would you be able to update your post with your `SearchAuxForm` code?  And can you clarify the expected behaviour?  For example: There is a page located at www.somewhere.com/book.  The has a form and a list of books.  There are three select boxes, one which represents columns in a table, on which represents operators such as (==, >=, <=, !=, <, >) and one which represents the value to query on.  When the user submits this form, without refreshing, the contents of the page should be updated to reflect the query constraints.

Comment: Hi @Lucas Scott, Thank you for taking a look at my second question, I have added two forms, the first is the form I use at the moment, and the second larger form is how I imagine the form might look. Warm regards Paul